# how to handle deprecated HandlerInterceptorAdapter in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, warnings, handlerinterceptor

**HandlerInterceptorAdapter is deprecated**

this is my code

```
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

public class MyInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter{
    
}
```

**screenshot of code**

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjrP2.png)

Comment: From the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/handler/HandlerInterceptorAdapter.html) of `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` - Deprecated. 
as of 5.3 in favor of implementing [HandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/HandlerInterceptor.html) and/or [AsyncHandlerInterceptor](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/AsyncHandlerInterceptor.html) directly.

Answer (score 20):

The Handler interceptor adapter deprecated because new HandlerInterceptor interface have default methods now. Simple remove HandlerInterceptorAdapter and implements HandlerInterceptor.